# MacVim :e expands to Edit, and Edit! won't let me discard changes?

Tags: edit, macvim

When I type :e, MacVim automatically expands this to :Edit. The problem with this is that I can't discard my current buffer with :Edit!, because I get an error message saying that "!" isn't allowed.

I have two questions:

1. Why does :edit! work and not :Edit!
2. Is there a way to disable this auto-expand feature in MacVim, or perhaps switch it to expand to :edit! and not :Edit! ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `Edit` is actually a command, do you have some plugin making it one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expansion happens immediately after typing the `e`, it might be due to a command-mode mapping (i.e. [`:map!`, `:cmap` or `:lmap`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-commands)). If it is only expanded after typing `e` followed by a space (or enter), then it might be an abbreviation (i.e. [`:abbreviate` or `:cabbrev`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Aabbreviate)).

You can temporarily avoid a mapping-based expansion by typing [Control‑V](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-V) or [Control‑Q](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-Q) before `e`. Another workaround is to type [Control‑F](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-F) while entering a command-line command (i.e. you are at the `:` prompt; or type `q:` instead of `:` when starting a command). This will bring up the command-line window so that you can edit your command via normal/insert modes (this avoids all command-line mode mappings).

Once you have a way to enter `e` into a command-line again, you can use [`:verbose`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Averbose) to find the source of the mapping:

```
:verbose cmap e
```

(You must either use the command-line window to type this literally, or enter it at the command-line by typing a Control‑V or Control‑Q before each `e`.)

This will show you the definition of the mapping. Additionally, if it came from a plugin, then the source will be identified with a second line like `Last set from /path/to/some/file`.

Checking for an abbreviation is a bit tricker since there are two chances for expansion (while typing and when the command line is being parsed):

```
:verbose cab ^Ve
```

The `^V` needs to be an actual Control‑V. Usually you accomplish this by typing Control‑V twice (or Control‑Q, then Control‑V).

---

As for the `Edit` command itself, it is not a built-in command, so something plugin must be defining it. Very few built-in commands start with an uppercase letter, and all “user defined” commands must start with one; see [`:help E183`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#E183).

You can use `:verbose` again to find where `:Edit` was defined:

```
:verbose command Edit
```

I suspect the mapping/abbreviation and the command probably come from the same place.

---

You can manually disable a mapping-based expansion with `:cunmap` and an abbreviation-based expansion with `:cunabbrev`:

```
:cunmap e
:cunabbrev ^Ve
```

Again, you may need type Control‑V or Control‑Q before each `e`, and the `^V` must be a literal Control‑V (type Control‑V twice to enter it).

Unfortunately, you can not just put these in your `~/.vimrc` if the definitions are coming from a plugin because plugins are loaded after `~/.vimrc`. You should investigate the plugin to see if it offers a option to disable the intrusive mapping. Sometimes plugins check a [`:let`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Alet) variable to see if they should enable some feature. Maybe your problematic plugin has a “knob” that will let you tell it not to install its `e` -> `Edit` expansion. If not, you might be able to report a bug about `:Edit!` not working properly and ask for a way to disable the expansion too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use TextExpander, Typinator or some text expansion utility? If yes, those might be the culprit. As far as I know, MacVim does not expand text like that.